TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵcmp') in Angular 18
I'm trying to make the sorting of table work for /users that is defined in UserListComponent. The sorting functionality was broken by introducing NavbarComponent.
I tired to switch to standalone components when possible as suggested in this answer. I'm new to Angular and as far as I understand the @NgModule in DemoMaterialModule (main.ts) is quite useful because I don't have to import every single material module in every component.
Angular 18 promotes standalone way so it may be a good idea to go this route.
Is this the best fit form my use case? Would it be better to fully switch from my hybrid approach (standalone + modular) to standalone?

How to make it work?
GitHub
UPDATE:
Sort is not working.
Updated code. Added demo data to reproduce sort issue easily

UPDATE 2:
Finally made it working: GitHub commit

hope this helps!

Thank you for help! The code compiles. Error is gone. The issue is the sorting it not working...

Your answers was quite useful. Thank you very much! I accepted answers. The thing is when I try to fix one part, the other breaks. (May be a bit off-topic: https://external-preview.redd.it/nNfvY2LrZISn3aO3V5zzAM2pPgOH5tlsvlvtJ2XVhqI.gif?width=364&format=mp4&s=6faef90b0ff40e00646d9666e1afda6512396d29)

I can only guide to a solution, not provide bug free code, that is on you!

During conversion of standalone style to modular style, we are using components in the routing that are not imported in the AppModule that caused the issue mostly.
I converted the entire app to standalone, as was stated in an earlier question.
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {bootstrapApplication, BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from "@angular/material/autocomplete";
import {MatButtonModule} from "@angular/material/button";
import {MatButtonToggleModule} from "@angular/material/button-toggle";
import {MatCardModule} from "@angular/material/card";
import {MatCheckboxModule} from "@angular/material/checkbox";
import {MatChipsModule} from "@angular/material/chips";
import {MatStepperModule} from "@angular/material/stepper";
import {MatDatepickerModule} from "@angular/material/datepicker";
import {MatDialogModule} from "@angular/material/dialog";
import {MatDividerModule} from "@angular/material/divider";
import {MatExpansionModule} from "@angular/material/expansion";
import {MatGridListModule} from "@angular/material/grid-list";
import {MatIconModule} from "@angular/material/icon";
import {MatInputModule} from "@angular/material/input";
import {MatListModule} from "@angular/material/list";
import {MatMenuModule} from "@angular/material/menu";
import {MatNativeDateModule, MatRippleModule} from "@angular/material/core";
import {MatPaginatorModule} from "@angular/material/paginator";
import {MatProgressBarModule} from "@angular/material/progress-bar";
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from "@angular/material/progress-spinner";
import {MatRadioModule} from "@angular/material/radio";
import {MatSelectModule} from "@angular/material/select";
import {MatSidenavModule} from "@angular/material/sidenav";
import {MatSliderModule} from "@angular/material/slider";
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from "@angular/material/slide-toggle";
import {MatSnackBarModule} from "@angular/material/snack-bar";
import {MatTabsModule} from "@angular/material/tabs";
import {MatToolbarModule} from "@angular/material/toolbar";
import {MatTooltipModule} from "@angular/material/tooltip";
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {provideHttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {provideRouter, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {AppComponent} from "./app/app.component";
import {CarListComponent} from "./app/cars-list/car-list.component";
import {CarComponent} from "./app/car/car.component";
import { routes } from './app/app.routes';
import {MatSortModule} from "@angular/material/sort";
import {UserCarsComponent} from "./app/user-cars/user-cars.component";
import {UserComponent} from "./app/user/user.component";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {MatFormFieldModule} from "@angular/material/form-field";
import { NavbarComponent } from './app/navbar/navbar.component';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { UserListComponent } from './app/user-list/user-list.component';


@NgModule({
  exports: [
    CdkTableModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
  ]
})
export class DemoMaterialModule {}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    DemoMaterialModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    RouterModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    UserListComponent,
    UserComponent,
    CarListComponent,
    CarComponent,
    UserCarsComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: [
  ],
  providers: [provideHttpClient()]
})
export class AppModule {}


platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
  ngZoneEventCoalescing: true
})
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

Please find below code changes for fixing sorting, do let me know if any doubts.
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSort, Sort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { Car } from "../models/car.model";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CarService } from '../services/car.service';
import { FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { debounceTime, takeUntil } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

function compare(a: number | string, b: number | string, isAsc: boolean) {
  return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cars',
  templateUrl: './car-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./car-list.component.css']
})
export class CarListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'make', 'model', 'numberplate'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Car>;
  cars: Car[] = [];
  filterControl: FormControl = new FormControl('');
  private ngUnsubscribe = new Subject<void>();

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;

  constructor(private carService: CarService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router) {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Car>();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeTable();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)).subscribe(params => {
      const { find } = params;
      this.filterControl.setValue(find || '');
      this.applyFilter(find || '');
    });
  }

  initializeTable() {
    // Fetch cars from service
    // this.carService.getCars().subscribe((data: Car[]) => {
    //   this.cars = data;
    //   this.dataSource.data = this.cars;
    // });
    // fake API call
      this.cars = [
        {
          id: 1,
make: 'car1',
model: 'asdf1',
numberplate: '12344',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
make: 'car2',
model: 'asdf2',
numberplate: 'h4r5ty',
        },
        {
          id: 1,
make: 'car33',
model: 'asdf33',
numberplate: 'zxcvfbdf',
        },
        {
          id: 1,
make: 'car45',
model: 'asdf45',
numberplate: 'asdfae',
        }
      ];
      this.dataSource.data = this.cars;

    // Set filter predicate
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter: string): boolean => {
      return data.make.toLowerCase().includes(filter) || data.model.toLowerCase().includes(filter) || data.numberplate.toLowerCase().includes(filter);
    };

    // Subscribe to changes in the filter control with debounce
    this.filterControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
    ).subscribe(value => {
      this.applyFilter(value);
    });
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
    // Update the URL with the new filter value or remove the parameter if the filter is empty
    this.router.navigate([], {
      relativeTo: this.route,
      queryParams: filterValue ? { find: filterValue } : {},
      queryParamsHandling: filterValue ? 'merge' : ''
    });
  }

  applySort(sortState: Sort) {
    const data = this.cars.slice();
    if (!sortState.active || sortState.direction === '') {
      this.dataSource.data = data;
      return;
    }

    this.dataSource.data = data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = sortState.direction === 'asc';
      switch (sortState.active) {
        case 'id':
          return compare(a.id, b.id, isAsc);
        case 'make':
          return compare(a.make, b.make, isAsc);
        case 'model':
          return compare(a.model, b.model, isAsc);
        case 'numberplate':
          return compare(a.numberplate, b.numberplate, isAsc);
        default:
          return 0;
      }
    });
    const sortField = sortState.active;
    const sortDirection = sortState.direction as 'asc' | 'desc';

    // Update the URL with the new sort value
    this.router.navigate([], {
      relativeTo: this.route,
      queryParams: { sort: `${sortField}:${sortDirection}` },
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
    });
  }

  navigateToCarDetail(car: Car): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/cars', car.id]);
  }
}

Github Repo

@J.Olufsen updated my answer!

Sorting is working. Thank you very much!

Do you have same errors in browser console? ERROR TypeError: this.sort is undefined
initializeTable user-list.component.ts:81
ngOnInit user-list.component.ts:39
..
 main.ts:123

@J.Olufsen comment out that line, its not needed
